# HOWTO configure some settings by default using a silent/unattended msi installer on WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an msi installer which i have created using [wixtoolset](https://wixtoolset.org/).

Now what I am trying to do is to configure some settings of my app just in the moment I launch the msi installer by passing some parameters to it so my app is going to be installed with those settings by default. In this way i can deploy my app with features a,b,c to a user and with some other features d,e,f to another user.

I need to distribute/roll out my application to multiple computers, so I need to do a silent/unattended installation without user intervention.

I have heard that passing parameters (custom actions) to the msi installer do not work in silent/unattended installations so how can I achieve this?

Comment: Settings or features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question. Your title says settings but your question mentions features.  Windows Installer has a property called ADDLOCAL which can be used to set which features to install.

msiexec /i foo.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn    <- install all features silently

msiexec /i foo.msi ADDLOCAL=A,B,C /qn <- install features A B C silently

This is only way way to do it. There's all the INSTALLLEVEL property and feature conditions.  Also if your talking settings your typically talking about secure custom public properties like

Then maybe in a registry value you use [SERVERNAME] to populate a registry value with the value of SERVERNAME.

msiexec /i foo.msi ADDLOCAL=A,B,C SERVERNAME=myserver /qn

Also be aware of mainteance mode (change) it's possible to add and remove features

msiexec /i foo.mai ADDLOCAL=A,B,C REMOVE=D,E,F /qn

Finally be aware that MSI doesn't persist properties (like SERVERNAME) so if you install with one value and do a repair it can get nulled out.  For this google  Wix Remember Property pattern  for examples of how to use a Registry Search to fetch the property back from the registry.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you well, ADDLOCAL is a property that comes built-in with Windows Installer, right? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/addlocal
On the other hand, if I install an msi file using the parameter ADDLOCAL = A, B, C and then for some reason I do a repair, what's happens? repair knows that I installed features A, B and C and it will re-install them automatically or otherwise repair will do a ADDLOCAL = ALL ?

Comment: Yes and feature states are persistent. Same for components unless they are marked transitive.

Comment: But if I repair it from "Add or remove programs" in Windows, how Windows knows that I installed it with features A, B, C? I would like to understand it.

Comment: That's a different question.  Windows Installer stores information about installed products under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer